# How to run sudo commands using shell-command?

Tags: shell-command, sudo

When I run any sudo command using shell-command—for example, `(shell-command "sudo ls")`—I get the following error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

How can I get around this? I'm guessing it should be possible to tell Emacs somehow what my askpass program is?

By the way, the correct askpass program is currently stored in the environment variable `$SSH_ASKPASS`.

Comment: The environment variables outside of Emacs are passed on to the shell commands.  According to sudo's man, it uses the variable SUDO_ASKPASS or the option -A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `default-directory` points to a sudo-ized path, `shell-command` uses this environment. Try

> ```
> (let ((default-directory "/sudo::"))
>  (shell-command "ls"))
> ```

The password will be asked interactively.

Comment: Great, that works! Is there a way to make the output buffer stay visible if the command exits with a failure?

Comment: `shell-command` is just for getting the output as string. For more complex scenarii, `process-file` might be better suited.